# Lua string space, letters and digits

Tags: string, lua

I want to check whether a string only contains letters, digits and space. I found this function to check that it's only letters and digits, but I'm not sure how to allow spaces too:

```
string:match( "%W" );
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `%w` matches an alphanumeric character. The uppercase version `%W` matches its complement, i.e, a non-alphanumeric character.

To get the complement of alphanumeric and whitespace, try the pattern `[^%w%s]`.

```
str:match("[^%w%s]")
```

returns a non-`nil` value when a string is NOT only letters, digits, and spaces.